# how to change the reducer case function to immutable js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

i have a code to update the count value of object. now i need to convert it to immutable.js. i am pretty much new to immutable.js. so how can i convert this code to immutable.js format.

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState={
    ingredients: {
        salad:0,
        meat:0,
        cheese:0,
    },
    totalprice:40
}
const ingredientCost = {
    cheese:20,
    meat:30,
    salad:10,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_INGREDIENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                ingredients:{
                    ...state.ingredients,
                    [action.ingredientName] : state.ingredients[action.ingredientName]+1
                },
                totalprice: state.totalprice + ingredientCost[action.ingredientName],
            };
        case actionTypes.REMOVE_INGREDIENT:
        return {
            ...state,
            ingredients:{
                ...state.ingredients,
                [action.ingredientName] : state.ingredients[action.ingredientName]-1,
            },
            totalprice: state.totalprice - ingredientCost[action.ingredientName],
        };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
export default reducer;
```

i tried to change the code to immutable format:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';
import  Immutable  from 'immutable';


const initialState=Immutable.fromJS({
    ingredients: {
        salad:0,
        meat:0,
        cheese:0,
    },
    totalprice:40
})
const ingredientCost = {
    cheese:20,
    meat:30,
    salad:10,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_INGREDIENT:
            return state.ingredients[action.ingredientName].merge(state.ingredients[action.ingredientName]+1)    
        case actionTypes.REMOVE_INGREDIENT:
        return {
            ...state,
            ingredients:{
                ...state.ingredients,
                [action.ingredientName] : state.ingredients[action.ingredientName]-1,
            },
            totalprice: state.totalprice - ingredientCost[action.ingredientName],
        };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
export default reducer;
```

but while doing this i am not able to update the state. i am getting initialstate but i dont know how to update it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `initialState` is immutable object, You cant use `state.ingredients`, You should use

- `state.set()` / `state.setIn()` or
- `state.update()` / `state.updateIn()` or
- `state.merge()` / `state.mergeIn()`

read: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map

Comment: return state.setIn(['ingredients',action.ingredientName],          ) how can i give updating option here after comma. i gave ++1 but i am not able to update it